# Sending email after backup (Windows Server 2008)

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, email, windows-sbs-2008, windows-sbs

I have a client who is using Windows Server 2008 (Small Business Server), and using Windows Backup.

What I need to do is configure the backup task so that, upon completion, it sends an email notifying the client of backup success or failure. I have been able to find that task in task scheduler, and even see where I can send an email...but I cannot find a way to make the content of the email different based on success or failure of the backup. How might I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I think you can do: Find a success and a failure event in the Windows Backup event log, right click each event type and select the option "Attach task to this event", then set the parameters for the task for sending an email, yadayadayada. This should create two tasks that send one or the other email for each backup: one if the backup succeeds and a success event is logged, or one if the backup fails and a failure event is logged.

If there are no failure events in the Windows Backup log, then run the job, make it crash, confirm that a failure event is logged, and then set up the task for the failure event.

Answer (score 1):

http://sbs.codeplex.com has examples of backup error codes.